# iOS Saving Web Service Data to Device

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data, nsdata

My situation is that I have a universal app that talks to an sql database via odata. When the user retrieves data over the line I want to save that to the device so that if the user stops the app or the app crashes than I can rehydrate the saved device data and we will not have to re-retrieve the data when the app starts again.

My question is for this sitatuation is it more beneficial to user coredata to save the data to an sqllite db or should I save the data to the documents directory? The data can be serialized into an NSData object which could be saved straight to the device from what I have read, where as saving NSData objects to sqllite is not what it is designed for.

Im looking for the most performant of the two options and also the option that will not restrict as much on size restrictions.

Looking forward to any advice that you can give me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the nature of the data and how will you be using/presenting it? To accurately answer this question, that bit of information is highly relevant.

Comment: if you go the core data /sqllite route, it doesnt limit the binary data you wnat to store, rather than storing it as a field you can store it in a file and store the file path in a core data field

Comment: The data is for data throughout an enterprise system. So the data will be presented in listings, combos, bound forms etc etc. So it will be continually retrieved and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the size of the data is small enough to fit in memory with no problems, then you will probably get the best performance from serializing an NSData object.

If, however, the data reaches the point where it strains memory usage, you will want to use something like Core Data or sqlite to persist it to the disk and only load objects in memory you are using at the moment.

Comment: By "serializing an NSData Object" you mean, saving it the NSData object to disk and loading it when needed?

Comment: Yes, saving to disk, and then restoring from disk. Assuming you actually do parse the NSData into objective-c objects, you could use a variety of methods, such as NSKeyedArchiver http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html .

Comment: Cheers for your response. Do you know if there is any limitations for how much an app can store to disk? Or is it just limited by the space available on the device? Thanks

Comment: As far as I can recall, the only limit is the available space on the device.